# Missing js/css files in frontend of contao cms

Tags: php, macos, apache, docker, contao

i was making a local copy of a working live instance of a contao website (contao version 3.4.0).

i copied web folder and made a dump of database. the site works on local in general but several files (e.g. slider js/css) are missing with following error in console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)". i also cleared contao cache.

Atm i really cant imagine what could cause this. most of the files are located in path modules/system/. i tried to 775 over the whole project but same problem. i also made a new dump of live database and reimported it, same problem.

i have to say that i am using docker for mac: https://github.com/webdevops/php-docker-boilerplate. the contao project is located in app folder on root level.

maybe some problem with ownergroup. i would really need some help here because i am not that educated in server configuration.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with some .htaccess files in some modules folders e.g. system/modules/news/assets/.htaccess

writing this configuration to .htaccess files solved the problem

```
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
         Require all granted
    </IfModule>
```